# Can you help me identify this vine please?

Tags: identification, vines

[image]

Can I get some help to identify the vine please? I have dug a couple up which have single large root, almost like a parsnip?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it might be some kind of Marah, or wild cucumber. Apparently (by wikipedia), there are lots of different species of this. When you say it has a root like a parsnip, it sounds like it might be one of them, because they seem to have interesting taproots.

Example here:

[image: humongous wild cucumber root]
[Boyce Thompson Arboretum](http://boycethompson.blogspot.com/2011/10/normal-0-false-false-false-en-us-x-none.html)

Hope your weed isn't as bad as that.

Comment: WOW.  I thought it was Rubus, Blackberry initially but a big tap root?  Interesting Lorel...!

Comment: I *think* I can see in the picture some long curly tendrils that the plant uses to grab onto its environment and help it climb. Blackberries don't have those tendrils, but squashes & cukes do. ...(grapes do too of course)

Comment: Nice catch...great eyes.  I think I can as well and that is a perfect point.  I like that thinking...wish we had a way to blow up pictures more clearly.  Good job, Lorel!

Comment: Thanks for the comments, turns out it’s white bryony?